# In FitNesse, can variables be defined in terms of other variables?

Tags: .net, fitnesse

In FitNesse, can variables be defined in terms of other variables?

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
    int a=3;
    int b=a;
```

To make this concrete, I have a variable defining the date:

```
    !define clock.date {2/2/2009}
```

I then want to define some other variable ${other.date} based on it, something like:

```
    !define other.date {=${clock.date}=}
```

However, this doesn't work.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current parser has an issue with nested braces so you can use the alternate syntax for define:

!define x {stuff}

!define y (${x})

This restriction will be removed soon and you'll be able to do !define y {${x}} etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried this (since it's an obvious thing to do) but it failed.  However, we're on a pretty old version of FitNesse.

Gonna mark this as accepted ... thanks!